# how populate columns dependng found value?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with customers ID and columns related to months (1,2,3....)
I have a column with the number of months since last purchase
I am using the following to populate the relevant months columns

```
dt.loc[dt.month == 1, '1'] = 1
dt.loc[dt.month == 2, '2'] = 1
dt.loc[dt.month == 3, '3'] = 1
```

etc,

How can I populate the columns in a better way to avoid creating 12 statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [`pd.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
pd.get_dummies(dt.month)
```

---

Consider the dataframe `dt`

```
dt = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        month=np.random.randint(1, 13, (10)),
        a=range(10)
    ))

   a  month
0  0      8
1  1      3
2  2      8
3  3     11
4  4      3
5  5      4
6  6      1
7  7      5
8  8      3
9  9     11
```

Add columns like this

```
dt.join(pd.get_dummies(dt.month))

   a  month  1  3  4  5  8  11
0  0      8  0  0  0  0  1   0
1  1      3  0  1  0  0  0   0
2  2      8  0  0  0  0  1   0
3  3     11  0  0  0  0  0   1
4  4      3  0  1  0  0  0   0
5  5      4  0  0  1  0  0   0
6  6      1  1  0  0  0  0   0
7  7      5  0  0  0  1  0   0
8  8      3  0  1  0  0  0   0
9  9     11  0  0  0  0  0   1
```

If you wanted the column names to be strings

```
dt.join(pd.get_dummies(dt.month).rename(columns='month {}'.format))

   a  month  month 1  month 3  month 4  month 5  month 8  month 11
0  0      8        0        0        0        0        1         0
1  1      3        0        1        0        0        0         0
2  2      8        0        0        0        0        1         0
3  3     11        0        0        0        0        0         1
4  4      3        0        1        0        0        0         0
5  5      4        0        0        1        0        0         0
6  6      1        1        0        0        0        0         0
7  7      5        0        0        0        1        0         0
8  8      3        0        1        0        0        0         0
9  9     11        0        0        0        0        0         1
```